# Ensemble with voting in deep learning models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a multimodal deep learning classifiers with RGB-D images. i have developed two seperate models for each case. The first one is a LSTM with CNN in the begining for the RGB images with shape `(3046,200,200,3)` , and the second one is an LSTM  for the depth images with shape `(3046,200,200)` . I'm trying to figure out how i can do Ensemble-with-voting.

I have done the bellow code tha finds the most voted labels but seems not working well. Is there any another way to do late fusion to the models?

```
labels = []
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('Saved/LSTM_RGB/LSTMRGB.h5')
predictsRGB = np.argmax(loaded_model.predict(x_testRGB), axis=1)
labels.append(predictsRGB)

loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('Saved/LSTM_DEPTH/LSTMDEPTH.h5')
predictsDepth = np.argmax(loaded_model.predict(x_testDepth), axis=1)
labels.append(predictsDepth)

print(labels)
# Ensemble with voting
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = np.transpose(labels, (1, 0))
print(labels,labels.shape)
labels = scipy.stats.mode(labels)[0]
labels = np.squeeze(labels)
print(labels)
print(labels.shape)
```

Comment: Ensemble voting should have an odd number of classifiers to break ties.  You only have two classifiers here.

Comment: @rayryeng what can I do alternatively, in order to have a late fussion result?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classifier, in that cases directly voting does not make sense because how to resolve the ties?

Since you are doing np.argmax on models' prediction, I believe the models output probabilities as a prediction. If you can not introduce a third model, you can average out these probabilities and then take argmax.

As an example: Model 1 says class 1 with prob 0.9 and class 0 with probability 0.1
whereas model 2 says class 1 with probability 0.3 and class 0 with 0.7.

The averaged probabilities would be:
Class1: 0.6 Class0: 0.4 and you would go for class1. In a way, it makes sense since model 1 was much more sure about its prediction than the model2

Comment: Can you suggest a way to implement ( there is a ready-made function?), or should i get the predictions manualy for each model class? – jvario 7 mins ago

Comment: I dont think that a built function exists. What does model.predict return? without any argmax. Isnt it of shape (number of classes,)? if yes you can just add predictsRGB and predictsDepth and divide by two

Comment: You mean something like this?  `(depth_model.predict(x_testDepth)+rgb_model.predict(x_testRGB))/2` ?

Comment: yes if the output of .predict is as I said probabilities for each class. They might also be raw scores, in that case before adding you should normalize each of them separately. If .predict return [8,4] you should convert it to [0.66, 0.33] and then add.

Comment: It returns an array  with shape  (3000,10) with decimals propabilites (i guess), if I do a run with argmax `(AvgModelTrans=np.eye(10, dtype=int)[np.argmax(AvgModel, axis=1)]
)` on the already sumed predicted array with classification report seems that working.